# VS Code Author and File Information

Tags: visual-studio-code

For every single file I save, VS code shows this information

When I save a file with VS code, the and file author information suddenly shows on top. I have tried but I cannot disable it.

Can I get a helping hand on how to get rid of it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eARt.jpg)

Comment: What extensions do you have installed? Can you include your settings.json?

Comment: It must be one of your extensions doing that.  Try running the `Bisect` command to figure out which one.